# How To Validate Cconfirm password using Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am Trying to validate the password and confirm password using javascript but not working , here is my code can anyone tell whats wrong with it ?

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
    var pass,cpass;
    pass= document.getElementByName("password")[0].value;
    cpass= document.getElementByName("cpassword")[0].value;   
         if(pass!=cpass){
        alert("Password And Confirm Password Should Be Same");
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<label>Password     : </label><input class="ip1" type="password" name="password" required/>
<label>Confirm Password     : </label><input class="ip1" type="password" name="cpassword" required/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this link will help you http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Password-and-Confirm-Password-validation-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx

Comment: Did you open the browser's dev console to check for errors? (F12, in most browsers.)

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this

First of all replace button type "submit" to "button". Submit button will always submit your form before JQuery works.
**HTML**

```
 <form>
        <label>Password     : </label><input class="ip1" type="password" id="password" required/>
        <label>Confirm Password     : </label><input class="ip1" type="password" id="cpassword" required/>
        <input type="button" value="submit" id ="BtnSubmit" />
      </form>
```

JS

```
$("#BtnSubmit").click(function(){
    var pass,cpass;
    pass= $("#password").val();
    cpass= $("#cpassword").val();   
         if(pass!=cpass){
        alert("Password And Confirm Password Should Be Same");
        return false;
      }
  $("form").submit();
    });
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqxyzq

Comment: nice, but he was also asking what's wrong with his code

Comment: Yes. I just show him better way to improve his code

Comment: *"Submit button will always submit your form before JQuery works."* - No it won't. And a submit button is more semantically correct. Better to add a submit handler to the form that cancels the submission if validation fails - which is what the OP's code already did. Also, as per the JavaScript tag's [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
    var pass,cpass;
    pass= document.getElementById("pass").value;
    cpass= document.getElementById("cpass").value;   
         if(pass!=cpass){
        alert("Password And Confirm Password Should Be Same");
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<label>Password     : </label><input class="ip1" id="pass" type="password" name="password" required/>
<label>Confirm Password     : </label><input class="ip1" id="cpass" type="password" name="cpassword" required/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        if($("#pwd").val() != $("#cpwd").val()){
            alert("Password And Confirm Password Should Be Same");
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<label>Password     : </label><input class="ip1" id="pwd" type="password" name="password" required/>
<label>Confirm Password     : </label><input class="ip1" id="cpwd" type="password" name="cpassword" required/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per the JavaScript tag's [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected." (But if you are going to use some other library anyway, at least tell the OP which one it is.)

Answer (score 0):

you mistyped `getElementByName` and it should be `getElementsByName`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var pass,cpass;
        pass  = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
        cpass = document.getElementsByName("cpassword")[0].value;

        if(pass!=cpass){
            alert("Password And Confirm Password Should Be Same");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <label>Password     : </label><input class="ip1" type="password" name="password" required/>
    <label>Confirm Password     : </label><input class="ip1" type="password" name="cpassword" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

its `document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;`..its not getElement its `document.getElementsByName(""cpassword"").value;`  ....and also call validate function in submit button

```
onclick=validateForm();
```